# how to use external jars in Cloudera hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, protocol-buffers, cloudera

i have a cloudera hadoop version 4 installed on my cluster.
It comes packaged with google protobuffer jar version 2.4.
in my application code i use protobuffer classes compiled with protobuffer version 2.5.

This causes unresolved compilation problems at run time.
Is there a way to run the map reduce jobs with an external jar or am i stuck until cloudera upgrades their service?

Thanks.

Comment: try adding it as an external jar into your project. remove the old one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can run MR jobs with external jars.

Be sure to add any dependencies to both the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` and `-libjars` upon submitting a job like in the following examples:

You can use the following to add all the jar dependencies from current and `lib` directories:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`echo *.jar`:`echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g'`
```

Bear in mind that when starting a job through `hadoop jar` you'll need to also pass it the jars of any dependencies through use of `-libjars`. I like to use:

```
hadoop jar <jar> <class> -libjars `echo ./lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /,/g'` [args...]
```

**NOTE:** The `sed` commands require a different delimiter character; the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is `:` separated and the `-libjars` need to be `,` separated.

EDIT: If you need your classpath to be interpreted first to ensure your jar (and not the pre-packaged jar) is the one that gets used, you can set the following:

`export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true`

Comment: i already have the jar in my $HADOOP_CLASSPATH. The problem is the Hadoop uses a different version that comes bundled with the Hadoop. I want to be able to use my jar (which is a better version) over the jar that is bundled with the Hadoop

Comment: Ah, try setting it to use your classpath first like in the edit to my post.

Comment: i got sidetracked by more urgent issues, ill be sure to update (and accept your answer :) ) if it will work!