# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error while trying to read a word document in mapreduce using Apache POI

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-poi

I am trying to read a word document file in my mapreduce program, for which I have used an user defined `fileInputFormat` classes as `WordDocxInputFormat` and `WordDocxInputFormatRecordReader`. In the `WordDocxInputFormatRecordReader` class I am using Apache POI to read the word `.docx` file. But I am getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` run time error.
I am using Eclipse and  Hadoop-0.20.2 in windows 7 platform.
I have defined my `CLASSPATH` as : `JAVA_HOME\lib;C:\cygwin\home\bmohanty6\poijars\;`
In `C:\cygwin\home\bmohanty6\poijars\` I have kept below jar files(in the attached image ) needed for POI and also added them into `Project->property->libraries->add external jar`.

[image]

I am getting error as

```
13/09/17 12:35:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201309101108_0040_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at WordDocxInputFormat$WordDocxInputFormatRecordReader.next(WordDocxInputFormat.java:112)
    at WordDocxInputFormat$WordDocxInputFormatRecordReader.next(WordDocxInputFormat.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
```

Here is my WordDocxInputFormat.class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;  
import java.util.logging.Logger;  

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;


import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.*;

/**
 * Reads complete documents in Binary format.
 */
public class WordDocxInputFormat
    extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text> {

    public WordDocxInputFormat() {
        super();
    }

    protected boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path filename) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public RecordReader<Text, Text> getRecordReader(
            InputSplit split, JobConf job, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        return new WordDocxInputFormatRecordReader((FileSplit) split, job);     
    }

    /**
    * WordDocxInputFormatRecordReader class to read through a given binary document
    * Outputs the filename along with the complete document
    */  
    public class WordDocxInputFormatRecordReader
        implements RecordReader<Text, Text> {

        private final FileSplit fileSplit;
        private final Configuration conf;
        private boolean processed = false;

        public WordDocxInputFormatRecordReader(FileSplit fileSplit, Configuration conf)
            throws IOException {
            this.fileSplit = fileSplit;
            this.conf = conf;
        }

        @Override
        public Text createKey() {
            return new Text();
        }

        @Override
        public Text createValue() {
            return new Text();
        }

        @Override
        public long getPos() throws IOException {
            return this.processed ? this.fileSplit.getLength() : 0;
        }

        @Override
        public float getProgress() throws IOException {
            return this.processed ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean next(Text key, Text value) throws IOException {
            if (!this.processed) {

                Path file = this.fileSplit.getPath();
                try{
                    XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(file.toString()));
                    XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
                    key.set(file.getName());
                    value.set(we.getText());
                }
                catch(IOException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(WordDocxInputFormatRecordReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                this.processed = true;
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: add jars and restarts server

Comment: I have already restarted my system 2 times after adding jars and classpath. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you made sure that you're deploying the POI jars along with your Hadoop job? My hunch is that you're pushing out your code to the cluster, but forgetting to push the deps

Comment: @Gagravarr -  I am really sorry, i could not get your point. Actually I am doing it in single node. How to deploy POI jars to cluster. Please help me, I am new to hadoop and java as well

Comment: There's nothing special about POI jars, read any hadoop tutorial that covers deploying code with dependencies and do the same for the POI jars (plus the dependencies of the POI jars, and any other dependencies you might have!)

Comment: See duplicate questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122701/how-to-use-external-jars-in-cloudera-hadoop) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532648/hadoop-submit-a-job-with-lots-of-dependencies-jar-files) for example

Answer (score 1):

> "But I am getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException run time error"

If you are getting this error and runtime but not when you compile,  then you are almost definitely using a different setup when you run the program as to when you compile.  i.e when you compile the compiler looks in the area with the jars, but when you run the program it is looking somewhere else and not finding them hence why your error would only appear at runtime.  If this is indeed your issue I have a couple of suggestions:

If you are using eclipse as your tag suggests check your build path, I don't know how eclipse works with compiling and running so you may need to check into that.

Alternatively if you will be using the jars regularly you can try adding them into the external lib of your jvm as this tutorial [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/ext.html) shows and then ensure you use that jvm for compiling and running.  Placing them in the area shown in the tutorial allows the compiler to check for the jars automatically at compile and runtime when that jvm is used.

Hope this helps,
Good luck!